# listeners not receiving events using phonegap build / sencha touch app one windows mobile

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a Sencha Touch app that we're building using phonegap build and installing on Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8 devices.

The application launches as expected on all platforms, however as part of the launch process, we are registering for several events:

```
    document.addEventListener("pause", this.handlePause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", this.handleResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.handleBackButton, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", this.handleMenuButton, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", this.handleInternetConnectionAvailable, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", this.handleInternetConnectionUnAvailable, false);
    document.addEventListener("batterystatus", this.handleBatteryStatus, false);
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", this.handleOrientationChange, true);
```

This is included in the launch function of the profiles.

On iOS and Android (and on BB10 build via webworks 2) this is working and we are receiving these events as expected.

On Windows Phone 8 however, we are not getting any of them.

Our config.xml file includes the following plugins currently:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
```

Has anyone come across similar problems?  I've tried for a couple of days to get around this and I'm not getting any where!

I've tried registering for events on window and document which seems to make no difference.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: OK, it turns out a team member had removed the "phonegap.js" reference from the index.html file and committed the change for reasons I cannot begin to understand, so everything does in fact work as expected.

The only remaining issue I have is that WP8 does not seem to get the orientationchange event, which is not part of the phonegap events api so I'm not surprised that's not supported.  There's lots of answers for fixing orientation but I can't see anything so far about actually reliably detecting a change.  If anyone has any clues on that it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: make it simple, what error you got?

Comment: For others who may come across this, IE10 on Windows Phone 8 does not provide/support orientation change events in any way.  I've a reasonable solution working by watching for window resize events and looking for the dimensions to change.  If you do this, be sure to handle the display of the keyboard which will resize one dimension of the viewport, but not both.